# ul + span in line(with CSS?)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using bootstrap for pagination, here simplified code.

```
<div style="margin:20px 0px 20px 0px">
  <ul class="pagination" style="display:inline">
    <li>page 1</li>
    <li>page 2</li>
  </ul>
  <span>ajax-loader</span>
</div>
<form>text fields, button for send msg</form>
```

Ajax loader looks fine, right after pagination buttons, but form's elements ignore my div and go right after my ajax loader(same line), like there is no div. Brake line(br) not working too, i don't understand why.

So i want:

> "pagination-ajaxloader"
>   "other data"

I have:

> "pagination-ajaxloader-otherdata"

I tried to use float for ajaxloader, but i want it near pagination from right side. Looking for some advise, thank you.

Comment: How about adding a separate `<div class="row">` for both the components?

Comment: @ODelibalta `display:inline` is only for the `ul`. The `div` is still a block element.

Comment: @ODelibalta He says the form is going inline. He wants the `span` to be inline.

Comment: Don't meddle with the layout styles for the Bootstrap components themselves. In your case, instead of giving `display:inline` (which collapses it to 0 x 0) to the pagination, split them into rows and columns (if necessary) and use positioning properties if you want to fine tune the appearance.